# Problem in code of C language In applying Arithmetic Operation between Inputs?

Tags: c, char, switch-statement, scanf, conversion-specifier

/*I took input from user as 'a' and 'b' but  in 'b' it takes 0 by default ..... whatever i give in 'b' as input it showing 0 as 'b' on applying Operation....
C code ......*/

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a,b;
    printf("Enter the I no. : ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Enter the II no. : ");
    scanf("%d",&b);

    char c;
    printf("Enter the Operation : ");
    scanf("%s",&c);

    switch (c)
    {
    case '+':
        printf("Addtion of %d and %d = %d",a,b,a+b);
        break;
    case '-':
        printf("Subtraction of %d and %d = %d",a,b,a-b);
        break;
    case '*':
        printf("Multiplication of %d and %d = %d",a,b,a*b);
        break;
    case '/':
        printf("Division of %d and %d = %d",a,b,a/b);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `"%s"` is used to read a string of characters. To read a single character, use `" %c"`. Note the space before the `%`. You need that space.

Comment: Suggest that you learn some basic [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) steps. Print the values of a, b, and c after they've been input. Are they what you expected? Does the switch execute the correct case arm?

Comment: Since the `scanf("%s", &c)` call treats `c` as an array of at least 2 characters, the null byte overwrote something — probably the least-significant byte of `b`.  Enter a number bigger than 255 for `b` and see what you get.

Comment: When asking for debugging help, you should provide an **exact copy** of the input and an exact copy of the output and a sample of the output desired instead. This could help diagnose whether the stray null character from the errant use of `%c` is the cause or there is some other problem.

Answer (score 1):

You declared an object of the type `char`

```
char c;
```

So to input a value for the object you need to use conversion specifier `%c` instead of `%s`

```
printf("Enter the Operation : ");
scanf(" %c",&c);
```

Pay attention to the leading space in the format string. It allows to skip white space characters.

Also before performing division you need to check whether `b` is not equal to `0`.

And it is desirable to include the case label `default` in the switch statement for an invalid inputted operation.

Also some operations as for example the multiplication can result in overflow. To avoid overflow you should cast operands to the type `long long int` In this case the calls of `printf` will look the following way as for example

```
printf( "Addtion of %d and %d = %lld\n", a, b, ( long long int )a + b );
```

Comment: "before performing division you need to check whether b is not equal to 0" and not `INT_MIN/-1`.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%d",&b);` appears to be correct code to read a decimal numeral into `b`. If a non-zero number is entered but `b` later appears to be zero, a likely explanation is that the mistaken use of `scanf("%s",&c);` writes a null byte into `b`.

`%s` is for reading multiple characters into an array of `char`. In addition to reading characters from input, it writes a null byte into the array to mark the end of the characters. However, `c` is a single character, not an array. If you entered a character such as “+” (followed by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>) then `scanf("%s",&c);` will write the character into `c` and then write a null character to the next byte in memory.

If the compiler happened to put `b` just after `c` in memory, that will alter the value stored in `b`.

Do not use `scanf("%s",&c);` to read a single character. Use `" %c"`. The space character tells `scanf` to skip white-space (such as the new-line character that will be in the input stream after the user enters a value for `b` and presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>) `%c` tells `scanf` to read a single character: `scanf(" %c", &c);`.